What is the list of AWS Kendra stopwords for thesaurus
Kendra thesaurus feature do not accept "stopwords". But as of today (May 2024) the documentation does not provide the full list of "stopwords".
Where can i find the "stopwords" full list to prevent the error ?

Your thesaurus 'name' is returning the following error message: Line
9676 isn't properly formatted. Synonym lines can't have stopword
terms. For example, 'The Kendra' is valid, but 'The' isn't. Remove the
stopword term and try your request again.

